# function to merge two dataframes and return int value like years

Tags: python-3.x

Returns a merged DataFrame containing the country name,  region and CO2 emissions, 
for a given year.

```
Parameters
----------
year : int
    The year of interest

Returns
-------
a DataFrame
   A pandas DataFrame with three columns titled 
   'Country', 'Region', and 'CO2 emissions'.
```

```
def mergeByYear(year):
    yearString = str(year)
    result = pd.merge(country1, emission, on = 'Country Name')
    return
```

```
Example
-------
>>> mergeByYear(2012)
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: my question is i have to make a function which will merge two dataframe and will return a combine dataframe . but we have to return value in years

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the code from your question is working, you just need to tweak what you return:

```
def mergeByYear(year):
    yearString = str(year)
    result = pd.merge(country1, emission, on = 'Country Name')
    return result.loc[result['year'] == year]
```

Comment: by using  histograms and boxplots i have to explore the distribution of the CO2 emissions per person by region data set from  for a given year.

Hint: Use a for loop to consider multiple years like for decade use 10 as a step.

Comment: I don't understand what this has to do with my answer